# Remove Action from MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I am adding a widget to someone elses movieclip.

On stage is another movieclip which has an action inside the movieclip (getting to this by pressing F9 in Flash).

```
function onClicked()
{
    parent.onOldBtnClick("go");
}
```

What I need to do is to get rid of this behaviour and add my own action.

How can I override this action?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what the problem is. If you need to replace that behavior, why can't you just delete that call to the method and change the code to something else?

Comment: I am only adding an swf to the stage. So how do I find out what is calling the action and/or how do I change the action in the timeline of the stage from my imported swf?

Answer (score 1):

If it's ActionScript3, just `removeEventListiner` on the `MovieClip`, that triggers `onClicked()` and `addEventListener` for your own action. If you don't know the exact listener, you can trace it with `hasEventListener`. For more info on Events and how they work, you can read on [ActionScript3 referance](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html)

Comment: How do I find out which event triggers the onClicked() action. I can trigger the action by calling 
    notMyMovieClip.onClicked();
But notMyMovieClip returns false to hasEventListener and to willTrigger.

Comment: onClicked is not a listener function it's a custom function you could call it yourself by code. So it will always return false for both hasEventListener and willTrigger.

Comment: But how do I rewrite the this custom function?

Answer (score 0):

To override, just delete that line in the onClicked function and write your own. Care must be taken while writing your block of codes, mainly scope. Because your are writing the code inside the movieclip, if you are trying to access the another movieclip in stage(withour specifying parent or root or its actual scope) then it will throw error.

Comment: I cannot delete the line of code, as I am not the owner of the code. so I do not have access to deleting it other than while running and using actionscript. How do I delete it via AS3?

Comment: In the below comment, you have told that you are calling it like notMyMovieClip.onClicked(). So you can call your function instead of your function there, won't you?